# Removing duplicate paragraphs with Edit Pad Pro or Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have a `.docx`  file that contains mcqs which are in the format as shown below. The problem is there are many duplicate mcqs and I would therefore like to know if a regex can be created to detect all duplicate mcqs.

I have Edit Pad Pro 7,Notepad++,powergrep and sublime text. and all the regex that I have used until now deleted duplicates on a line by line basis, thereby deleting options from other questions even though the questions don't match.

So basically what I am saying is I need a regex that can delete all the duplicate mcqs only if the whole mcq matches, not individul lines or sentences.

I am a novice with respect to regex, so please excuse any inadequacies.

```
Lichen planus occurs most frequently on the?
A.  buccal mucosa.
B.  tongue.
C.  floor of the mouth.
D.  gingiva.

In the absence of “Hanks balanced salt solution”, what is the most appropriate media to transport an avulsed tooth?
A.  Saliva.
B.  Milk.
C.  Saline.
D.  Tap water.

Which of the following is the most likely cause of osteoporosis, glaucoma, hypertension and peptic ulcers in a 65 year old with Crohn’s disease?
A.  Uncontrolled diabetes.
B.  Systemic corticosteroid therapy.
C.  Chronic renal failure.
D.  Prolonged NSAID therapy.
E.  Malabsorption syndrome.

Lichen planus occurs most frequently on the?
A. buccal mucosa.
B. tongue.
C. floor of the mouth.
D. gingiva.
```

**expected result**

```
Lichen planus occurs most frequently on the?
A.  buccal mucosa.
B.  tongue.
C.  floor of the mouth.
D.  gingiva.

In the absence of “Hanks balanced salt solution”, what is the most appropriate media to transport an avulsed?
A.  Saliva.
B.  Milk.
C.  Saline.
D.  Tap water.

Which of the following is the most likely cause of osteoporosis, glaucoma, hypertension and peptic ulcers in a 65 year old with Crohn’s disease?
A.  Uncontrolled diabetes.
B.  Systemic corticosteroid therapy.
C.  Chronic renal failure.
D.  Prolonged NSAID therapy.
E.  Malabsorption syndrome.
```

Comment: I don't see duplicate with your example. lease, edit your question and give expected result.

Comment: Just changed it now.thnx.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(([^?]+\?\R(?:.+\.\R)+)[\s\S]+?)\2`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           : start group 1
  (         : start group 2
    [^?]+   : 1 or more any character that is not "?"
    \?      : a question mark
    \R      : any kind of line break
    (?:     : start non capture group
      .+    : 1 or more any character but newline
      \.    : a dot
      \R    : any kind of line break
    )+      : end group, must appear 1 or more times
  )         : end group 2
  [\s\S]+?  : 1 or more any character, not greedy
)           : end group 1
\2          : another occurrence of group 2
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
```

Comment: @den: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @den: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Is there a Way to mark the individual McQ as a pharagraph permanently .so that even ms word recognises it as a pharagraph.

Comment: it has worked but the problem is that it removes even the original for exp 
  input   =  pharagraph1,pharagraph2,pharapraph3,pharagraph1   result =pharagraph3,pharagraph3 .pharagraph 1 gets deleted completely i want a code that delets only the duplicate and maintains 1 copy of everything.hope i am clear.and thnx in advance

Comment: @den: That's strange, it works fine for me, I have Notepad++ `v7.5.6`.

Comment: me to ,but the problem is all pharagraphs that have duplicates are deleted . without maintaining at least one copy.maybe i am doing some thing wrong .please recheck if possible .thnx

Comment: i tested it on https://regex101.com/ .no change at all

Comment: @den: May be you have some hidden characters that make the paragraphs distinct. For example, in the given example, the last paragrap is not the same than the first, there are not the same number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Technically in the given input there are no duplicates as ‘A.  buccal mucosa.’ and ‘A. buccal mucosa.’ differ in number of spaces after 'A.'.
However, the intuition suggests that such cases should be somehow spotted.
As you mentioned in the comment that you are using https://regex101.com/ I will use this webpage to do the matches and replaces.

I selected flavor: javascript and set two flags in the regular expression section: g (global) and s (single line).


I will use 3 patterns to deal with this string.


The first pattern searches for identical question_and_answer occurences. If there are discrepancies between them, those won't be treated as duplicates.

If there are more than one duplicate all of them will be captured.


`(?<=^|\n)([^\n]+)(\n)(\D{1}\.\s+[^^]+?)(\n{2})(?=[^^]*\1\n\3)`


Input (TEST STRING):

```
Question 1?
A. SomeA1.
B. SomeB1.

Question 1?
A.     SomeA1.
B.     SomeB1.

Question 1?
A. SomeA1.
B. SomeB1.
```

Output (SUBSTITUTION): // one duplicate removed

```
Question 1?
A.     SomeA1.
B.     SomeB1.

Question 1?
A. SomeA1.
B. SomeB1.
```

[image]

If we just want to find duplicates based on the questions then this pattern should work but should only be used for information only. 
`(?<=^|\n)([^\n]+)(\n)(\D{1}\.\s+[^^]+?)(\n{2})(?=[^^]*\1)`

Input (TEST STRING):

```
Question 1?
A. SomeA1.
B. SomeB1.

Question 1?
A.     SomeA1.
B.     SomeB1.

Question 1?
A. SomeA1.
B. SomeB1.
```

Output (SUBSTITUTION): // it looks ok, but it's a trick and must be used with caution

```
Question 1?
A. SomeA1.
B. SomeB1.
```

[image]

Ideally if we know what kind of deviations we might find in the data we can clean the data before the first pattern is applied, like in the following example where multiple spaces are replaced with just one space.
Find: `(?<=\n)(\D{1}\.)(\s+)([^^]+?\n)`
Substitution: `\1 \3`
Input (TEST STRING):

```
Lichen planus occurs most frequently on the?
A.  buccal mucosa.
B.             tongue.
C.                        floor of the mouth.
D.  gingiva.
```

Output (SUBSTITUTION):

```
Lichen planus occurs most frequently on the?
A. buccal mucosa.
B. tongue.
C. floor of the mouth.
D. gingiva.
```

[image]

Comment: These regex don't work in Npp. What do you want to match with `[^^]*`?

Comment: @Toto, indeed those patterns do not work in N++ but I got the impression that @den is presumably interested in a solution rather than a solution purely in N++.  I also tried to solve it in N++ and those two patterns should do the job meaning that it's possible to remove multiple consecutive and non-consecutive duplicates. Just put `\n` in the replace textbox: (1)  `(^[^\e]+?$)(\R)(\D{1}\.\s+[^\e]+?)(\R{2})(?=[^\e]*\1\2\3)`; (2) `(^[^\e]+?)(\R)(\R)(?=[^^]*\1(\R|$))`. There will be too many new lines left but the data itself will be nicely structured and easy to work for humans and machines.

Comment: OK, but what are you trying to match with `[^^]*` and `[^\e]*`?

Comment: I often switch between different systems with many regex flavors and don't want to think each time what will capture for example a dot in a given context so I pick some character which I know for sure is not going to appear in the text like BEL (\a) or ESC (\e) and use it for matching as many characters as possible until limiting group is reached. In single line mode there's only one `^` 'start of a line' so I often use it for greedy capture. `[^^]*` means 0 or as many characters as possible.

Comment: `^` inside a character class doesn't mean "start of line" but it negates the character class when in first position else it means simply a caret `^ `, so `[^^]*` means not a caret 0 or more times.

Comment: `[^^]` means any character that is not start of a line. In single line mode there is only one `^` character per the whole text so when you use `[^^]*` it will capture all characters except the first character which is `^`.  It's a very powerful and convenient greedy pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong, `[^^]*` means not a caret 0 or more times, it will not match a caret in the middle of a string. Just test it. If you want to match all characters (including linebreaks), you can use for example `[\s\S]` or `[\w\W]`

Comment: Precisely speaking `[^^]` captures anything except `^` and `$`. Let's say I have a string `a`. For regex it is `^a$` (3 chars) and I apply the expression `[^^]*`. The regex checks: 1) is position 0 not a `^`? - No, don't match it because it is a `^`. 2) is position 1 not a `^`? - Yes, match it because it is `a`. 3) is position 2 not a `^`? - Yes, but don't match it because it is `$`. So it captures in your language 'not a caret 0 or more times' excluding `$`. `[^^]` has only one test to make whereas `[\s\S]` requires two tests to perform in order to establish whether to match the char or not.