# How to find and mark all duplicate paragraphs using Notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

There are PDF files with thousands of lines that I need to work on a regular basis. Duplicate paragraphs are very common so I'm hoping if there's some sort of automation to find and highlight all of them.

What I usually do is copy-paste the full PDF file in *Notepad ++*, so **what I'm looking for is a RegEx code** to execute in Notepad++.

I've found a line from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1321534/removing-duplicate-paragraphs-with-edit-pad-pro-or-notepad), but this is not working for my scenario.

`(([^?]+\?\R(?:.+\.\R)+)[\s\S]+?)\2`

I've also tried doing this in Word by using a [VBA code I found](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5450-word-find-duplicate-sentences.html), but this is taking forever to process since there's an average of 50,000 lines and 350,000 words per file. Even get a lot of not responding issue due to the amount of text it needs to process. *Or maybe because my PC is old*

A sample would be like this:

> Although failure to release garnishment upon filing of debtor’s
> bankruptcy petition vio- lated automatic stay, punitive damages were
> not warranted because court did not find ac- tions of respondents to
> be egregious violation of automatic stay, nor did court find that
> respon- dents acted with malevolent intent.
>
> Court need not consider whether elements of res judicata under
> Georgia law were met be- cause claim preclusion was inapplicable to
> debtor’s claim for punitive damages arising from stay violation.
>
> Although failure to release garnishment upon filing of debtor’s
> bankruptcy petition vio- lated automatic stay, punitive damages were
> not warranted because court did not find ac- tions of respondents to
> be egregious violation of automatic stay, nor did court find that
> respon- dents acted with malevolent intent.
>
> Court need not consider whether elements of res judicata under
> Georgia law were met be- cause claim preclusion was inapplicable to
> debtor’s claim for punitive damages arising from stay violation.

I would really appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Are you concerned at all about false-positives? What I mean is in legal docs is common to use the same stock paragraphs. Do you just need to remove duplicates that are close to each other, or can you just remove all duplicate paras? What type of regex does Notepad++ use (Perl? JavaScript?)?

Comment: Based on a search, it seems that it uses Perl. You're right, I'm only looking for paragraphs close to each other. But I'm not sure if that's the right choice since there are times duplicates happen after a span of many paragraphs.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to highlight only, and not replace those dupes. I just need to be aware if there are dupes and where are those, so I can change it in our CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

- `(([^?]+\?\R(?:.+\.\R)+)[\s\S]+?)\2`

with:

- `(([\S\s]+\R(?:.+\.\R)+)[\s\S]+?)\2`

because you haven't any question mark in your text.

- `[^?]+\?` means 1 or more non `?` followed by `?`
- `[\S\s]+` means 1 or more any character

Rest of the explanation can be found in the linked answer.

Note: I'm the author of the linked answer.

**Screenshot before:**

[image]

**Screenshot after:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot of taking the time to help me, really appreciate it. However, I tried pasting this to mark (highlight) only the duplicate paragraphs, but it's not working correctly. Can you please change the code so that it will be to highlight text instead of replacing? My goal is to be aware of duplicates so I can remove them from the CMS we use. Again thank you!

Comment: @ixcode: A simple highlight of the duplicate is not possible, sorry.

Comment: That's ok. Just a question, I tried to do what you did there in the screenshots, but I'm getting a **0 occurrences were replaced.** message. I did check ```Wrap around```, also ```Regular expression```. What maybe wrong in my set up?

Comment: @ixcode: Is the sample text you gave is correct? The regex is working for the **exact** text you've given in the question. If the real text is quite different, please, edit your question and give a real test case. May be the regex will be different.

Comment: I forgot to attach a link of my screenshot, doing (hopefully) exactly what's in your screenshots: https://ma-images-dump.imfast.io/EDEN/123.png

Apologies for taking too much of your time already.

Comment: @ixcode: Well, I'm surprised, I don't understand why it works here and not for you! Do you have the same linebreaks at the end of each sentences? May be a Notepad++ version problem, here, I'm using V7.8.7 64bit.

Comment: It's alright! I just wanted to try it but what I really need is a highlighter, unfortunately not possible with Notepad++. Thanks so much for all the help, @Toto! For now, I might stick with using VBA for Word.